# HTML5 download attribute not working cross-domain? Can it be made to work?

Tags: html, download

Consider the following page:

https://8chan.co/stackoverflow.html

Why does the first link work, but the second link doesn't? Do I need to send a certain header, or is it impossible to use the `download` attribute on a subdomain?

Answer (score 3):

Chrome actually does allow the download attribute on cross-origin files, without CORS headers, but Firefox chose not to, citing potential social-engineering attacks.

Check this link... [HTML5 download attribute not working when downloading from another server, even when Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to all (*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318017/html5-download-attribute-not-working-when-downloading-from-another-server-even)

You could fix it with php proxy file something like:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['file'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
header("Content-type: application/$ext");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name);
echo readfile($url);
?>
```

Comment: I know this was posted a while ago, but the mp4 file is corrupt when I use the above code...?

Comment: better not add trailing `?>` as it may corrupt the output

Comment: and what is `$ext`? that should be for file extension, but the variable isn't defined

Comment: "Chrome actually does allow the download attribute on cross-origin files" — I suppose at the moment Chrome also disables cross-origin download attr

Comment: This code allows header injection and serves a proxy for any file on the internet. **That should be considered unsafe.** Don't build something like this without a whitelist!