# HTML5 download attribute not working when downloading from another server, even when Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to all (*)

Tags: html, http, download, attributes, cross-domain

I have a download link like so:

```
<a href="foo.xls" download="bar.xls">Foobar</a>
```

This works fine when downloading a file on the same server, but when downloading from another server (Azure blob storage in this case) the filename stays as "foo.xls", even though the HTTP response comes back with the following header:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Is this by design or is there potentially another header I can to add to the HTTP response to get this to work?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, it is by design that the CORS headers have no affect on the `download` attribute. There are only two browsers that support the `download` attribute, Firefox and Chrome, and both browsers have a different policy on cross-origin files.

Chrome versions [prior to 65](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations) actually did allow the `download` attribute on cross-origin files, without CORS headers, but Firefox chose not to, citing potential social-engineering attacks.

MDN documents this behavior for Firefox 20 under the [`download` attribute section for the `a` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download), behavior that has not changed since.

> In Firefox 20 this attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin.

[This Bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676619) discussed the security concerns and the possibility of using CORS.

> When the user clicks such a link, the user will be prompted if they
>   want to download. It seems very easy for the user to make the mistake
>   of thinking that something on the original website is being
>   downloaded, and not something from bank.com.

> > Would it be possible to implement it with same-origin and CORS
> >     (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) in mind if you are questioning cross origin
> >     security? This is very useful feature for web applications (create Blob
> >     using JS and let user download it with some meaningful name)
>
> Google was opposed to using CORS for this.

There's also [this Bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=874009), which summarizes their decision from the other bug report.

> > Also, cross origin downloads are working perfectly in Google Chrome.
>
> Yes, and we think they're adding security bugs by doing that.

The Bugzilla issues don't seem to rule-out the possibility of using CORS for cross-origin `download` attribute support in the future, but right now using CORS headers does not do anything for the `download` attribute. It's possible that if other browsers start supporting the attribute, a consensus may yet be reached.

For sake of completeness, there is of course the `Content-Disposition` header which you can use to force a download from the other domain, but this does not provide the same functionality as the `download` attribute. It does have better browser support though.

Comment: During taking a look on a similar question to this. Just to up to date. Since Chrome  65, cross-origin download is no longer supported. See, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations.