# file download with custom name from remote url using javascript

Tags: javascript

I can download file(image/video) with custom name from same server using

```
<a href="img/a.jpg" download="test.jpg>
```

But can't download with a custom name when the src(href) is a remote source.

```
<a href="http://example.com/img/a.jpg" download="test.jpg>
```

How to solve the problem?

I found the same type of problems here,but nothing solves my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 download attribute not working when downloading from another server, even when Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to all (\*)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318017/html5-download-attribute-not-working-when-downloading-from-another-server-even)

Comment: it's not working in chrome and firefox also