# What S3 cors config should I use for Firefox html5 download attribute?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, firefox, amazon-s3

I'm using the HTML5 download attribute to allow users to download a video file from S3:

```
<a href="https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/video.mp4" download="video.mp4">Download</a>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and IE. From the following question I understand that Firefox wants CORS to be enabled to allow download attribute to work cross origin:

[HTML5 download attribute not working when downloading from another server, even when Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to all (*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318017/html5-download-attribute-not-working-when-downloading-from-another-server-even)

I've enable CORS on my S3 bucket using the following technique:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html

And this is my CORS policy:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Firefox still doesn't want to download the video. Any help, tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what is the error do you get ? Please share a screen shot or copy and paste those errors.

Comment: When I click on the download link using Firefox, the mp4 video opens in a new tab instead of downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Your CORS Policy is requiring an Authorization header. Change this to a wildcard.

In AllowedHeader change to `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>`

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of checks you need to do,

Make sure the content-type is  `application/octet-stream`. By default it is the same unless you changed it.

Firefox handles mp4 files differently,

```
1. Enter about:config in the address bar
2. Hit Enter
3. Click I’ll be careful, promise!
4. In the Search field, enter media.windows-media-foundation.enabled
5. Double-click the True in the media.windows-media-foundation.enabled result to change it to False
6. Close the browser tab
```

Then firefox should download the file.

**Reference:**

https://jdrch.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/how-to-prevent-firefox-from-playing-direct-link-mp4-files-in-the-browser/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for you help. But asking all users to change their Firefox config is not an option.