# HTML5 Download attribute not working for Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```html
<a class="download-btn" download="" href="https://example.com/test.pdf" id="download-pdf" target="_blank">Download </a>
```

I have simple above download link html5 code
it's not working in mozila and working fine in chrome

Comment: and what exactly is not working?

Comment: The browser is called Firefox (and is made by Mozilla, not Mozila). Chrome is not called Google. Internet Explorer is not called Microsoft. Edge is also not called Microsoft.

Comment: thanks, @Quentin  if you found the solution then plz let me know I will call it now onwards Firefox OK!

Answer (score -3):

use this

```
<a class="download-btn" download="filename.pdf" href="your file directory name put here/filename.pdf" id="download-pdf">Download </a>
```

please don't use website url in href tag

```
 wrong (https://example.com/folder name/filename.pdf )

right (../folder name/file name.pdf)
```

Comment: how its nonsense.   first check this in Mozilla then tell  me hows its nonsense.   
<a class="download-btn" download="filename.pdf" href="your file directory name put here/filename.pdf" id="download-pdf">Download </a>

Comment: In that it makes absolutely no difference whether you use an absolute or a relative URL ...

Comment: first check then i will accept it ! it is nonsense

Comment: I you are of the opinion that it would make any difference whatsoever whether a relative or an absolute URL was used - then please create a proper [mcve] somewhere that actually shows this live.

Comment: thanks for giving comment. but files are stored on S3 server so that's the region I need to mention absolute URL.

Comment: @CBroe nitpicking but in this exact case that would actually make an huge difference since what OP is experiencing is a cross-origin restriction. A relative URL wouldn't suffer from this restriction. (looking for some dupe...)

Comment: @Kaiido good point, cross-origin makes the difference here. But that still doesn’t make this a good answer, because it does not mention cross-origin as the reason, but just sounds as if there was a general difference between relative and absolute URLs.

Comment: @Kaiido https://stackoverflow.com/q/28318017/1427878 seems like an appropriate duplicate, I think.

Comment: @CBroe yep, already closed ;-)