# Download file using URL in firefox not working in angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My code works in google chrome that provide download and in firefox it always  show in new tab or selftab like XML file open in firefox how should I can download it?
So provide me some suggestion to download functionality in angular JS or Java script for Firefox!
 This is my code which I tried

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', url);
link.setAttribute('download', filename);
```

Comment: Where does `url` points to in regard to your current page?

Comment: URL points to s3-server to get  file

Comment: Do you know Balaji Damodare? He asked the same question 1hour before you did. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641375/html5-download-attribute-not-working-for-mozilla/48642634?noredirect=1#comment84283050_48642634

Comment: No I don't know but I am working from 2 days to find out solution for this, but I didn't find any solution

Comment: A possible workaround, depending on your s3 config: `fetch(url).then(r=>r.blob()).then(b=>{let a=document.createElement('a'); a.href=URL.createObjectURL(b);a.download=filename;document.body.appendChild(a);a.click();document.body.removeChild(a);`.

Comment: I know this createOvjectURL but dude i don't have any data or object , i just have URL for download file from s3 server

Comment: Try the code I gave (replacing `url` with the actual url) and cehck your console for an error. If it tells something like cross-origin request blocked, then you're screwed.

Comment: "fetch(url).then(r=>r.blob()).then(b=>{
                    let a=document.createElement('a');
                } " bro this code is not working in angular Js it give's syntax error first

Answer (score 5):

The anchor tag you are creating also needs to be added to the DOM in Firefox, in order to be recognized for `click` events.

```
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it directly open's text file in firefox, in chrome it's working fine

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that you have to encode the url with javascript function encodeURIComponent(URI) and, like Catalin lancu said before me, add the anchor tag to the DOM.

Here is a function I wrote some time back to download files:

```
function downloadFile(content, filename, type){
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = type+','+encodeURIComponent(content);
  a.target = '_blank';
  a.download = filename;
  document.body.append(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for Reply but I don't have file content, in my response I only get **file-Url and file name** so i can't use that