# Instead of downloading, files are opening in browser

Tags: javascript, html, download, anchor

My Pdf file is stored in google bucket, and i have a link let say https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketName/xyz.pdf. To download this file i am doing this,

```
<a href="https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketName/xyz.pdf" download> Download This File </a>
```

But when i click on this anchor tag, instead of downloading this file browser open this file in same tab even i try to download the file via javascript and was using this code .

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = 'File.pdf';
link.href = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketName/xyz.pdf';
link.click();
```

But same happen again file open in same tab instead of downloading. I don't know what is the main problem  ? Is this Google bucket is not letting file to download, or my chrome setting preventing files to download.
It is not downloading in Chrome i guess Chrome do allow the downloading from CORS files.

Comment: The download doesn't work with all browser. Maybe you need to add ˋwindow.locatioń´.

Comment: Download attribute won't work if the href link used is of different domain due to CORS [refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 download attribute not working when downloading from another server, even when Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to all (\*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318017/html5-download-attribute-not-working-when-downloading-from-another-server-even)

Comment: You can't force Chrome to download instead of opening the PDF with only clientside javascript. To force a download, it is necessary to add the 'Content-Disposition: attachment' to the HTTP header, and that can only be done in the server side.

Comment: @MatrixTai in that question Alexandar said it is working in chrome but in my scene it is not working in chrome also.

Comment: @AmitChauhan, at that time `cross-origin download` is allowed, but since chrome 65, due to security problem, it is also blocked. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations.

Comment: @MatrixTai so now to download files what should i do ?

Comment: Do it in back end, what language for ur back end?

Comment: you want me to make an api for it ?

Comment: Yes, you have no choice, but download the data in backend. Thus can then let client side downloads the pdf from your same origin.

Comment: ok thank you very much i really appreciate you effort and time to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 6):

As per [JavaScript/jQuery to download file via POST with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499597/javascript-jquery-to-download-file-via-post-with-json-data/26129406#26129406) construct a blob and use that to return the file reference for the link.

This will inform the browser of your intent in a standards compliance manner.

example ...

```
$.get(/*...*/,function (result)
{
    var blob=new Blob([result]);
    var link=document.createElement('a');
    link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download="myFileName.txt";
    link.click();

});
```

Comment: Have you try it to download a pdf? It won't work for up-to-date browser.

Comment: agree pdf also won't download

Comment: some browsers have built in functionality you cannot override ... it's a feature of the browser, after opening the browser will offer up a "save" option though as it has to download it in order to display in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

**Content-Disposition attachment** seems to work for me:

```
self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
self.set_header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename=learned_data.json')
```

## Workaround

***application/octet-stream***

I had something similar happening to me with a JSON, for me on the **server side** I was setting the header to
self.set_header("Content-Type", "**application/json**")
however when i changed it to:

```
self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
```

It automatically downloaded it.

Also know that in order for the file to still keep the .json suffix you will need to it on filename header:

```
self.set_header("Content-Disposition", 'filename=learned_data.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `link.target = "_blank";` this will open file in new tab and `link.download` will force it download.

Please tell if this works.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work , But for workaround in pdfviewer we have a button to download pdf, but it is not downloading the pdf directly from clicking on button.