# Image download link not working in Blogger

Tags: html

Whenever I add a download picture link to my website, the link does not work.

I have used all kinds of download HTML code.

If I click on my download link, the picture opens in a new window.

How do I set the button in a blog post so that my pictures are downloaded with one click?

After using all the code, my download link remains as just a hyperlink.

**HTML**

```html
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>link text</a>
```

Comment: can you please provide link to the page where this is happening?  and provide the link text - so we can see where it is on the page and look at the code?  i cannot see any links on the page in your question that say anything like "download picture".

Comment: i have just tested the links with the `download` attribute applied and i think the reason they are not working as expected is because the image is not hosted on your website (see information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28468261) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download)), searching now to see if there is a workaround.

Comment: i spent some time searching for a workaround, but couldn't see anything.  others might know a way.  ofcourse users can `right click on image > save as...`, but that's probably not what you are after.

Comment: Try with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click/55061628#55061628

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you need to open the images in same window and not in new window while clicked. To achieve that, you need to add target="_self" in the `<a>` tags as one of the attributes

`<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" target="_self">link text</a>`

Edited after seeing comment of GsGuri:

The question has three parts:

1. If I click on my download link, the picture opens in a new window.

Well, this has been answered above.

2. How do I set the button in a blog post so that my pictures are downloaded with one click?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29606450/3981539) is what you need. An alternative would be to zip all your pictures and give that as a result.

3. After using all the code, my download link remains as just a hyperlink.

If you use `<a href= "url" target="_self">Download</a>` it would remain as a hyperlink. To add button, you need to use a [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) with `formaction` defined for it.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
<a href="/link/to/image.jpg" download>
```

works, but HTML [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) attribute only downloads [same-origin URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

On your [private page](https://www.shayaripicture.com/p/download.html), you're trying to download [an off-site image](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-TzgsUtbtPjU/XUU2b41hd-I/AAAAAAAAC5c/ywp4-bsruEwoqc9PqP2Qp0i12jF9UKF4gCLcBGAs/s1600/bangkok-4309812_1920.jpg), which isn't possible.

Instead, create a copy of the image on your domain, and use the your code on it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your [private page](https://www.shayaripicture.com/p/download.html) and I found that the problem is the link of the image that you use.

Copying image location and use it is **NOT** the right way to make a downloadable image.

**The right way:**

Put the link of your blog `https://www.shayaripicture.com`
  and add the location of your image in your server
*for example*  `https://www.shayaripicture.com/myfile/myimage`
then add `/download?force=true`

your link will be: `https://www.shayaripicture.com/myfile/myimage/download?force=true`

**Live example:**

*Wrong way:*

```
<a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981822-0c0c5b070026?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" download >Download</a>
```

*Right way:*

```
<a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/WJAPg0sWsUQ/download?force=true" download >Download</a>
```

Comment: The browser should (and will) download an `<a>` link if it has `download` attribute...

Comment: No it will download the image NOT the link.
Please run and try it with  `download` attribute.

Comment: Yes, I've meant, it will download the image, so no need for `/download?force=true` if the `download` attribute set

Comment: That's true, adding both will not cause any problem with the browsers and will download the resources correctly. I use them both because the old browser will NOT read `download` attribute correctly and to avoid that and to give support to the old browsers I use both.

Comment: To use `/download?force=true` on an image, you need some server configuration that does it, that won't work on its own. For example, check this URL: [https://3.bp.blogspot.com/.../bangkok-4309812_1920.jpg/download?force=true](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-TzgsUtbtPjU/XUU2b41hd-I/AAAAAAAAC5c/ywp4-bsruEwoqc9PqP2Qp0i12jF9UKF4gCLcBGAs/s1600/bangkok-4309812_1920.jpg/download?force=true). It generates a `404 Not Found` error, since an image doesn't have `/download` subfolder...

Comment: I don't any about servers or server configurations. but this blog itself doesn't work normally!  Please check it:
 https://3.bp.blogspot.com

Comment: But the image works: [https://3.bp.blogspot.com/.../bangkok-4309812_1920.jpg](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-TzgsUtbtPjU/XUU2b41hd-I/AAAAAAAAC5c/ywp4-bsruEwoqc9PqP2Qp0i12jF9UKF4gCLcBGAs/s1600/bangkok-4309812_1920.jpg)... And, let's see any image (e.g. a w3css image [with `/download?force=true`](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg/download?force=true) and [without it](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg))

Comment: Alright, Thanks a lot. Please send me any reference to that server configuration. thanks

Comment: I don't know about such configuration... There should be a way to do that, but it will depend on what server & language are you using (PHP, Node.js > JavaScript, etc.)