# Change external file name download attribute

Tags: html, amazon-s3, download, save, anchor

I have coded a file download button and I want to change the file name when downloaded. The original file name is an ugly concatenation of Ids and is also signe by AWS.

When I use a local file, the downloaded is carried out as wished, with the modified name. But when I use the AWS stored and signed file I still get the real file name. Actually the issue occurs with all external files.

The example below shows the issue. The file should be download as newname.pdf. In my browser (Mac Chrome 67.0.3396.87) it's being downloaded as activities.pdf.

```html
<a href="https://www.ac-strasbourg.fr/fileadmin/pro/Formation_personnels/FOAD/activites.pdf" download="newname.pdf" target="_self">Test button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not allowed by External servers: CORS headers.

Related: [HTML5 download attribute not working when downloading from another server, even when Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to all (*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318017/html5-download-attribute-not-working-when-downloading-from-another-server-even)

Comment: Thanks. Can this be overcome by using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a `Service worker`, hook `fetch` event in Service worker and just replace the `Content-Disposition` header. The browser will then recognize the resource as an attachment with a new file name.

### How to

##### Client(browser)

1. Some AWS link here what you want change filename:

   > `https://s3.amazonaws.com/face_bucket/fake_filename?sign=SOMESIGN&token=SOMETOKEN`
2. You need to create some virtual pathname for attachment. Must be have same hostname. in this case I use `/attachments`
3. Modify download URL.

   > `/attachments/https://s3.amazonaws.com/face_bucket/fake_filename?sign=SOMESIGN&token=SOMETOKEN`
4. Append new filename to search parameters.

   > `/attachments/https://s3.amazonaws.com/fake_bucket/fake_filename?sign=SOMESIGN&token=SOMETOKEN&filename=NEW_URL_ENCODED_FILE_NAME`

##### ServiceWorker (service-worker.js)

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
  const { request } = event;
  
  // Is this a `modified URL` for an AWS S3 storage request?
  if (request.method !== "GET") return;
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  if (
    url.origin !== this.location.origin ||
    !url.pathname.startsWith("/attachments/")
  ) {
    // do nothing.
    return;
  }
  
  // get real download url
  const externalDownloadUrl = new URL(
    url.pathname.substring("/attachments/".length),
  );
  const filename = url.searchParams.get("filename");
  
  // copy searchParams except filename
  url.searchParams.delete("filename");
  for (const [key, value] of url.searchParams) {
    externalDownloadUrl.searchParams.set(key, value);
  }
  
  event.respondWith(
    this.fetch(
      externalDownloadUrl, 
      // ...some options such like headers for authentication or token for AWS or credential settings or cookie settings, if don't need just let empty.
    ).then(
      (res) => new Response(res.body, {
        headers: {
          // Add the necessary headers on the browser side here
          // ...someHeaders
          "Content-Disposition": `attachment; filename*=utf-8''${filename};`,
        },
        status: res.status,
        statusText: res.statusText,
      }),
    ),
  );
});
```

It will pretty work well.

Cons.

- Generated URL cannot be used for sharing outside WebApp. it only work within the scope of Web Application because it is just a fake URL to communicate with the Service worker.
- Also `save as` will not work.

P.S.

- I usually use the method of adding a search parameter to pass the file name I want to change to Service worker. but you can use another way what you want.
- Don't use `download` attribute of anchor element when use this trick. if `download` attribute work Service worker can't detect `fetch` event.