# Download an image instead of opening it in new tab

Tags: html, image, download

I am trying to download an image on click and using "download" attribute of HTML5 for this. But it is redirecting the user to a new tab instead of downloading the image.

```
<a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Stephenson%27s_Rocket_drawing.jpg" download="myfile.jpg">Click to Download</a>
```

How can I sort out this issue?

Comment: "download" attribute method is only available with relative files. Check the answers of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click

Answer (score 5):

I tried to change the path from the href attribute to download and it worked `<a href="" download="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Stephenson%27s_Rocket_drawing.jpg">Click to Download</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Most browser (Chrome, Firefox) block download from CORS origin (external domains) for safety reasons.

So instead of a "silent" download, they force the user to navigate to the screen.

-[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61597967/3739410)